# Print feature file names while running all the cucumber features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

When I run all my cucumber features my system hangs, there seems to be a memory leak. I would like to find out which features create this problem. There are lot of feature files so I cannot run them individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the pretty formatter will print the feature and scenario names as the tests run

```
cucumber --format pretty
```

You can also add this to the cucumber.yml config file if you are using rake to run the cukes.

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying now, but this prints lot of text. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I know :) Afaik, if u just want the filenames, you have to write ur own cucumber formatter https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters